# Set pod resources from config map

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to set the resources of my pod from a config map

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu:
    valueFrom:
     configMapKeyRef:
       name: config
       value: CPU_REQUEST
```

But get error "got map", expected "string"

Comment: K8s doesn't support `valueFrom` from any field. You'll need to use helm, kustomize, or something like flux if you want that to be dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources cannot be configured through configmaps, they need to be configured as part of the [podspec](https://k8s-examples.container-solutions.com/examples/Pod/Pod.html#resources_and_limits/)